# how to pass variable into conditional join in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join

earlier sorry if my english bad

first i have variable like this

```
$data[code] = "xyz123";
$data[type] = "train";
```

and the query i write in model like this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.id = table1.id');
$this->db->select('table3', 'table3.id = table1.id AND table1.code LIKE $data[code] AND table1.type LIKE $data[type]');
```

But when i try, its not working and i think the syntax AND and LIKE i write is wrong to. Please anyone know the solution?

Thank you before.

Comment: use `"` instead of `'`. e.g. `"table3.id = table1.id AND table1.code LIKE $data[code] AND table1.type LIKE $data[type]"` instead of `'table3.id = table1.id AND table1.code LIKE $data[code] AND table1.type LIKE $data[type]'`

Comment: plus, while refering to array keys, use either `'` or `"`. e.g. `$data['code']` or `$data["code"]`

Comment: in common query pass the variable to query like this `"table3.id = $data['type']"` right? so in the active record i can write like that?

Comment: @KhalifaEsha did you check the answers ?

Comment: because the project is being worked on, I use a raw query, so I have not tried it
but can I ask, when Events like after `join` as above, what is the condition of `AND` or `OR`, or whether I can decide for themselves?

Comment: @Deepanshu ah, sorry my fault not select but it must be join i should write it, anyway maybe the question will be suspend after i try it i will be tell you soon, but before that thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to try this :

```
$this->db->select('table1.*,table2.*,table3.*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.id = table1.id');
$this->db->join('table3', 'table3.id = table1.id');
$this->db->like('table1.type', $data['type']);
$this->db->like('table1.code', $data['code']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try CI like function:

```
$this->db->like('type', $data['type']);
$this->db->like('code', $data['code']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data["code"] = "xyz123";
$data["type"] = "train";

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.id = table1.id');
$this->db->select('table3', 'table3.id = table1.id AND table1.code LIKE '.$data["code"].' AND table1.type LIKE '.$data["type"].'');
```